# AAPT error after updating gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

Updated Gradle on an old project to latest version and I get this error: .gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\CreditCardEntry-1.4.8.10.aar\453339e1f1fb2382e8ce2362a0acdedd\res\values\values.xml:11:5-54: 
AAPT: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

I can't figure out why this error appears and where to fix.

Values.xml file in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="null_color" type="color">234234</item>
<color name="text_helper_color">#a8a8a8</color>
<declare-styleable name="CreditCardForm"><attr format="boolean" name="include_exp"/><attr format="boolean" name="include_security"/><attr format="boolean" name="include_zip"/><attr format="boolean" name="include_helper"/><attr format="color" name="helper_text_color"/><attr format="color" name="text_color"/><attr format="color" name="hint_text_color"/><attr format="color" name="cursor_color"/><attr format="string" name="card_number_hint"/><attr format="reference" name="input_background"/><attr format="boolean" name="default_text_colors"/><attr format="boolean" name="animate_on_error"/><attr format="dimension" name="text_size"/></declare-styleable>
<item name="cc_card" type="id">2222</item>
<item name="cc_ccv" type="id">4444</item>
<item name="cc_entry" type="id">1000</item>
<item name="cc_entry_internal" type="id">3000</item>
<item name="cc_exp" type="id">3333</item>
<item name="cc_form_layout" type="id">1111</item>
<item name="cc_four_digits" type="id">6666</item>
<item name="cc_zip" type="id">5555</item>
<item name="text_helper" type="id">2000</item>
<string name="CreditCardFormCardNumberHint">1234 5678 9012 3456</string>
<string name="CreditCardNumberHelp"/>
<string name="ExpDateFieldHint">MM/YY</string>
<string name="ExpirationDateHelp">Expiration date (MM/YY)</string>
<string name="SecurityCodeFieldHint">CVV</string>
<string name="SecurityCodeHelp">Security code (CVV)</string>
<string name="ZipCodeFieldHint">   ZIP   </string>
<string name="ZipHelp">Zip code of billing address</string>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please post values.xml file

Comment: @UmangBurman Added values.xml

Comment: Check if there is any library added via the "lib" folder

Answer (score 4):

**either** remove all inner values from all of those items of `type="id"` ...because this is illegal (and it always was illegal, but only had been tolerated previously) - it does not even serve the least purpose. the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id) also explains this... you could change the type of the resource from `id` to something more suitable, alike an `integer`:

```
<item name="cc_card" type="integer">2222</item>
<item name="cc_ccv" type="integer">4444</item>
<item name="cc_entry" type="integer">1000</item>
<item name="cc_entry_internal" type="integer">3000</item>
<item name="cc_exp" type="integer">3333</item>
<item name="cc_form_layout" type="integer">1111</item>
<item name="cc_four_digits" type="integer">6666</item>
<item name="cc_zip" type="integer">5555</item>
<item name="text_helper" type="integer">2000</item>
```

both would be valid resource `XML`; better use `integer` when required to access these values.

also those `color` resources do not belong there, and one of them is missing the `#` prefix; [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color).

Comment: This is a transformed file in .gradle folder that (from my best guess) is transformed from Stripe or tipsy stripe project though. How would I go about getting these changed?

Comment: @ruffen you could check out the source-code from https://github.com/tipsi/CreditCardEntry and then add it to your project as a library module; this would give you full control over these resources... or fork that repo, fix it and then create a pull request, which might be (or might not be) accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Martin, we ended up removing Tipsi Stripe all together.

Comment: @ruffen what did you use instead? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Stripe was actually used for something that's a dead part of the app (long story), so we haven't replaced it yet. Maybe try and make our own native implementation wrapped in React.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  How do you get rid of Stripe?  I cannot see where it is included?

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states you need to make sure there is no inner values to the item elements throwing the exception.

In some cases these can be from external libraries so cannot be modified directly, in this case create a file called ids.xml in the folder res/values.

In here you can override any items causing issues, for me I added the following to get over the issue stated in the question.

```
<resources>
    <item name="cc_card" type="id"/>
    <item name="cc_ccv" type="id"/>
    <item name="cc_entry" type="id"/>
    <item name="cc_entry_internal" type="id"/>
    <item name="cc_exp" type="id"/>
    <item name="cc_form_layout" type="id"/>
    <item name="cc_four_digits" type="id"/>
    <item name="cc_zip" type="id"/>
    <item name="text_helper" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

[image]